# Automatically installing multiple apps on Android devices when connected to a linux system

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, udev, fastboot

I had written some scripts using Ubuntu 14.04 and `adb` to automatically configure 100´s of Android smartphones.
To achieve that I used an `udev` rule to identify if an USB device is attached to the pc and if that's the case I call my scripts to install some apps onto the devices.

So far, so good but there are some problems.
At the moment we are connecting 5 devices at the same time, but it happens quite often that on one of the devices one ore more apps are not being installed.
It does not follow a pattern, it just happens randomly.
Sometimes also the performance of the computer decreases during the day.

Here is my `udev` rule:

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}!="1d6b", ATTRS{idVendor}!="203a", ATTRS{idVendor}=="****", ATTRS{idProduct}=="****", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/selectDevices.sh"
```

The first script in /usr/local/bin/ to identify the devices on witch the apps should be installed

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 2
Pid=/home/android/Schreibtisch/PID

for DEVICE in `adb devices | tail -n +2 | grep device | awk '{print $1}'`;
do

  if [ ! -f $Pid/$DEVICE.pid ];
  then

    touch $Pid/$DEVICE.pid
    sh /usr/local/bin/touchDevices.sh $DEVICE

  fi

done
```

and the last script to install the apps

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/android/Desktop/Apps

for APK in $(ls *.apk);
do
    adb -s $1 install $APK
done
```

**Edit 1:**
I´ve tried it like Alex P. suggested it or in my interpretation of his answer. 
Pass the serial to a tmp script and the tmp script is calling the actual installation script with `at now`. Before the installation script starts it sleeps 2 seconds.
But the problems still exist. Maybe I need to log what's happening during the installation but at the moment I have no clue how to do that.

**Edit 2:**
After some time I think I found something but I still have no idea why.
I think adb has problems when two devices want to install one app at the same time. I Managed it to receive an error message like `rm failed for /data/local/tmp/foo.apk, No such file or directory`.
After that I switcht to first copy the Package to the devices and then install them with the shell package manager, but still no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run multiple linux systems configured to automatically run `adb` and `fastboot` commands on device enumeration which process hundreds of Android device connections per day without a hitch. Based on my experience I have the following advice for you:

- you should wait couple of seconds after device enumeration before
  sending any `adb` commands
- you should not run any long running processes directly from `udev` rule. You can use `at now` command to "decouple" your `adb install` commands from `udev`
- there is no need to use `adb devices` to get the serial number. Let your `udev` rule to provide it to your script as a parameter.
- no need to use `bash` where `sh` is enough
- use full paths where possible

Your install script should look like this:

```
APKDIR="/full/path/to/apks"
PIDDIR="/full/path/to/pid"
ADB="/full/path/to/adb -s usb:$1"

if [ ! -f $PIDDIR/$2.pid ]; then
    touch $PIDDIR/$2.pid
    CMD="sleep 5"
    for APK in $APKDIR/*.apk; do CMD="$CMD; $ADB install $APK"; done
    echo "$CMD" | at -M now 2>/dev/null
fi
```

Add the call to your install script to the end of the `udev` rule:

`, RUN+="/bin/sh /full/path/to/the/script.sh %k $env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}"`

If this setup still does not produce stable results - try increasing the `sleep` duration in the script.

Also it helps to assign bigger number (90+) to your `udev` rule

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but i have some questions.

Comment: Where would you suggest to place the waiting command before sending adb commands? In the udev rule or just in the first line of the script?
How would you use `at now` with the udev rule? something like this? `RUN+="at -f /pathto/script.sh $attr{serial} now"`. Problem is he won´t accept the parameter if I do it in that way.
Or should i call a script which would do the work with `at now`?

Comment: Thank you very very much. 
I just had to increase the sleep duration.